# Does a Charitable donation deduction depend on the price or the value of the item?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, donation

When donating a product, does it matter what the original cost of the product was? For example, what if a $1000 product was purchased for $50? I know it's the reasonable market value of the product now, just using that as an example.

Answer (score 8):

The IRS doesn't care about purchase price of donated items, it's all about fair market value (FMV) at time of donation.

Generally, if the value is over $5,000 you'll need an appraisal, if not, you can determine FMV yourself, using the guidelines set forth in [IRS Publication 561](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p561.pdf)

The IRS defines Fair market value as:

> Fair market value (FMV) is the price that property would sell for on
>   the open market. It is the price that would be agreed on between a
>   willing buyer and a willing seller, with neither being required to
>   act, and both having reasonable knowledge of the relevant facts. If
>   you put a restriction on the use of property  you donate, the FMV must
>   reflect that restriction

Comment: Thanks. And is there any sort of annual limit? I'm now able to itemize deductions so it feels like a good time to donate a lot of old stuff but I don't want to hit any caps. Also, my understanding is that large deductions tend to flag audits. Are those audits generally for only the year in question or do they wind up auditing everything from X number of years? I've done nothing knowingly wrong any year, just curious.

Comment: Your total charitable deduction can't exceed 50% of your AGI, for the normal Goodwill trips less than $250 in goods the standard slips they provide are adequate with a good faith estimate of FMV. From $250-5,000 (for a single donation/group of related donations) you need one of the form letters they produce indicating the value of the donation, and over $5k you need an appraisal. Here's a more detailed article with some of the issues you can run into: http://www.thetaxadviser.com/issues/2016/jan/bad-news-for-noncash-contributions.html

Comment: Thanks! Any feedback on the audit question?

Comment: They can certainly do a multi-year audit, I don't think they'd bother unless there was suspicion of fraud. Just make sure your donations are well-documented, don't commit tax-fraud, and audits shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Thanks. When I last donated to Goodwill (some TVs at a few hundred dollars), they only gave me a paper with their info/signature on it for me to fill out. Was this right?

I'm trying to maximize this of course legally. Would anyone be able to help me identify the concerns/forms needed in the following?

1) 70 articles of clothing all in good condition. I use the Goodwill guide & come up with a total value of $300.
2) High end table and chairs that has a brand new retail value of $5,000. It has some scratches and is used so estimated value maybe $2,000.

Comment: One other question is if it is the individual donation event, or all donations over the whole year? If I donate $300 in clothes today, another $300 in 4 months, then what?

Comment: @iq78 What I meant in a comment above was that the slips you fill out yourself should be used only for donations up to ~$250 per trip, in that $250-5,000 range you want written acknowledgment from Goodwill. Here's a really good article that has good details:  http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2011/03/28/getting-the-most-from-your-charitable-deductions/
It indicates you have to think thrift store prices for donations, so that $2k table might really be $500, and you might be better of selling that on craigslist than donating it.

Comment: You should report back on if Goodwill will provide anything beyond their diy donation slip, I'm curious. I think I'd probably take pictures of the things being donated as additional documentation, to be extra cautious, unless Goodwill has a good mechanism for documenting large donations.

Comment: Thanks. In the form for under 5000, that link indicates the IRS wants to know how you obtained the item. Do they care? Does it impact anything?

Comment: @iq78 There are some situations where donations aren't qualified, but they probably use it to help identify fraud/evasion.